# Custom Login form with PHP and Ajax check username and display profile picture

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm trying to do something "different" with my login page, but i think i'm doing somthing wrong or not understanding the process.

Right now, my users table are like:

user_id, username, password, profile_picture, first_name, last_name

What i want is, when you click in the input text (on focus) you start typing your username, once you click out, the ajax will check this user and return at the top the profile picture for that account.

Here it's an example for this but using gravatars: [Example Here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?http://demos.9lessons.info/login_gravatar/index.html)

Can someone help me to understand how this request can be done with ajax and php?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you currently doing? Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myInput").blur(function(){
        // On exit, Get Image data
        $.get("getUserImage.php", { user: $(this).val() }, function(data){
            if(data != "error"){
                $("#userImage").attr("src", data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP (getUserImage.php):

```
<?php
$user = isset($_GET['user'])?$_GET['user']:"";

if(empty($user)){
    die("error");
}

// connect to MySQL DB w/ MySQLi
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userImage FROM table WHERE user=?")) {
    // bind parameters
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
    // execute query 
    $stmt->execute();
    // bind result variables
    $stmt->bind_result($image);
    // fetch value
    $stmt->fetch();
    if(!empty($image)){
        printf("http://www.example.com/%s", $image);
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
    // close statement
    $stmt->close();
}
// close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, i just did it, i was about to paste my code here but you really got what i need here. thank you so much mate. You Rock!